# jquery document click function is not working , wont fired

Tags: jquery

**javascript**

```
$(document).on("click",".pushStateLink",function() {
    // do some magic with $(this) element
    alert("pushstate");
});
```

**html**

```
<a class="pushStateLink" href=""></a>
```

My intention was to set a globe click handler to trigger all the class name pushStateLink, I was using this, but it wont work.

How do I set a globe click function handler?

I mean all my site which named pushStateLink class should be fire the same function.

How do i make it happen?

Comment: Its working, check the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/66bw5u4h/20/

Comment: this should work. do you have any error in browser console (f12)? Have you included jQuery reference? Try putting this code inside `$(document).ready(function(){})`

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code just after the closing body tag.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('.pushStateLink').click(function(){
    alert("pushStateLink");
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: if i use this the ajax return in my content having that class wont work.

Answer (score 0):

- first link `jQuery`,correctly (online or offline). and do like this.

  `$(document).ready(function(){
          $(".pushStateLink").click(function(){
               alert("push state")
          });
      });`

Comment: if i use this the ajax return in my content having that class wont work.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is working, with some modifications:

1. add text inside `<a>`;
2. add "#" inside `href`.

If this does not work, what error you get in the console?

I created [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3r06fg1y/) for you.

Comment: if i use this the ajax return in my content having that class wont work.

Answer (score 0):

Your code, As it is, Just inside a snippet: with jQuery linked and text inside `<a>`

```js
$(document).on("click", ".pushStateLink", function() {
  // do some magic with $(this) element
  alert("pushstate");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="pushStateLink" href="">This</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that your link element is not accessible. There is no physical dimensions for your anchor tag. Please try something like this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).on("click", ".pushStateLink", function () {
                // do some magic with $(this) element
                alert("pushstate");
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <a class="pushStateLink" href="">Sample</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Here the anchor tag is accessible due to its content or set a height and width to your anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the anchor tag with the innerText in it. Also check for the jquery where it is getting loaded. Here is the [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iamkarthik08/tf3qjz0f/)

```
 <a class="pushStateLink" href="">Click</a>

 $(document).on("click",".pushStateLink",function() {
   // do some magic with $(this) element
   alert("pushstate");
 });
```